# multiple pager on a single page

Tags: magento

In my customer review page

There presents 2 pager

I don't know how to delete the pager please help me

i am a magento beginer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toolbar section will be placed on your themes "review/customer/list.phtml". If it is not found there you can find this file in your base theme folder. Just comment this line

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

Thats it. You are done.